# Canceling a Paypal payment through IPN 'cmd'

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Is there a value defined by Paypal for '**cmd**' parameter (which is used to verify the IPN response by sending **cmd=_notify-validate** along with the received values) just to cancel the payment? Something like **cmd=_notify-ignore**?

The reason I need this is, I am maintaining a configuration file (I am working with PHP) and I can set **"Allow_Payments"** value to **"Yes"** or **"No"**. So enabling and disabling payments in Paypal time to time is sort of a messy solution. And the other issue is my "Buy Now" buttons are placed over different sites but all of them uses the same IPN Listener. That is why I am looking for a solution which I can use inside the IPN Listener. That is why I thought 'cmd' parameter will be helpful in this scenario.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have the wrong idea for the IPN.

The PayPal IPN is simply a listener or handler. Your IPN will be triggered *after* a successful payment has taken place.

I think it would be wrong to implement a cancel command fired from your IPN, as this will cancel payment after it is received- and is annoying for a user who has just made this payment.

A better alternative is to use a catch-all processing page before a PayPal payment page. All buy now buttons would direct to this document hosted on the same domain as your IPN (Creating a checkout style flow). Payment data would need be validated to prevent fraud (such as payment amount & business_email), then your "Allow_Payments" flag will be checked. If payments are allowed and we have valid payment data, proceed to PayPal payment.
This way, your users will be stopped before they make a payment and there is no hassle to cancel or refund.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I think your suggestion is more appropriate than mine. But just for knowledge, is there a way that I can inform Paypal through the **cmd** parameter that I want to cancel the payment?

Comment: I believe you can refund payments through the API.

Here is the documentation provided by PayPal:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_RefundTransaction

Sample usage: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_RefundTransaction_php.txt

Comment: What about a limited item? User A clicks the buy button, starts the payment, but while User A is logging in on Paypal user B starts buying this item aswell.

Answer (score 3):

For your server (the shop) to inform PayPal about the quantity and price of the product(s) that have been bought, your server typically sends back a HTTP redirect to the customer's browser.  This causes the customer's browser to be redirected to PayPal where payment takes place.

A vulnerability lies in this redirect. If the shopper has control of their browser, they can intercept this redirect and set the price of the product(s) to 0$.

The ONLY opportunity you REALLY have to accurately check that this hasn't happened is at the IPN stage. If you detect that something unexpected has happened to the price/quantity, you'd have to cancel the transaction at that point (post payment).